# Alternate definition of joule Thomson coefficient

Tags: thermodynamics

We know that Joule-Thomson coefficient is defined as
$$\mu_{jt}=\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)_H$$

Using the cyclic rule for partial derivatives it can be written as
$$\mu_{jt}=-\frac{\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right)_T}{\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P}$$

Which is equivalent to

$$\mu_{jt}=-\frac{\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right)_T}{C_p}$$

My question is can we write simmilarly

$$\mu_{jt}=-\frac{\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\right)_T}{C_v}$$